# Subquery returns different result than when called on its own

Tags: mysql, sql

Using GROUP BY in a MySQL subquery returns results not appearing when calling the GROUP BY query on its own.

This example is about as stripped down as I can make it.

I feel like I'm missing something elementary about using GROUP BY in a subquery, but haven't found an existing question or tutorial that addresses this particular issue.

First, build the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    Id INT
    Email VARCHAR(20)
    );

INSERT INTO Person VALUES (1, "a@b.com");
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (2, "c@d.com");
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (3, "a@b.com");
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (5, "c@d.com");
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (7, "e@f.com");
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (11, "e@f.com");
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (13, "g@h.com");
```

Now compare these two pairs of queries:

Test 1: subquery using explicit IDs

```
SELECT Id FROM Person WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 7, 13)
```

returns Id (1, 2, 7, 13)

```
SELECT Id FROM Person WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Person WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 7, 13))
```

returns Id (1, 2, 7, 13)

Test 2: subquery using GROUP BY for Email uniqueness (gives first in each group)

```
SELECT Id FROM Person GROUP BY Email
```

returns Id (1, 2, 7, 13)

```
SELECT Id FROM Person WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Person GROUP BY Email)
```

returns Id (1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)... not (1, 2, 7, 13), as expected.

I expected the output of the compound query on both of these tests to be 
Id (1, 2, 7, 13)
since the subquery in each outputs 
Id (1, 2, 7, 13)
as input to the top-level query.

This leads me to believe that the *displayed* results are not actually the full results (at least, when it comes to a GROUP BY). Any elucidation on this confusing situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In most versions of sql `SELECT Id FROM Person GROUP BY Email` is not valid. It's a curiousity of MySQL and best ignored.

Comment: Looks like the optimizer is omitting the GROUP BY clause in the subquery (since it makes no sense to it?).

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT Id FROM Person GROUP BY Email
```

This query is invalid according to the SQL standard. You group by `Email`. So you get one result row per `Email`. Then you want to show the ID for the `Email`. But there is not *the* ID per `Email`, there can be many. For `Email = 'a@b.com'` for instance there are the IDs 1 and 3. The DBMS should raise an error. But MySQL silently substitutes this with

```
 SELECT ANY_VALUE(Id) FROM Person GROUP BY Email
```

i.e. returns an arbitrarily chosen value. It's left to chance whether the query returns `ID` 1 or 3 for `Email = 'a@b.com'`.

This explains why you get different results. One time the DBMS chooses this value one time the other.

Comment: `'...ANY_VALUE...'` (well, newer versions, perhaps)

Comment: @Strawberry: Well, under the hood. Maybe it doesn't really replace it, but it behaves as if it `ANY_VALUE` had been used.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know - this query *should have failed* (which is what I expected) but MySQL doesn't error-check enough. Thanks!

Comment: @mcarlisle: Correct. You can `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` to have MySQL raising the error.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner GROUP BY seems to be ignored in the subquery. No error is raised: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vTj3A8AjYg4cwZy3KXZn7p/0

Comment: @Paul Spiegel: Yes, this is strange. According to the docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html MySQL should reject such queries. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I agree - It's a bug. Not the first one related to missing ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY errors. But returning all IDs is even more strange (IMHO). BTW: using `ANY_VALUE()` returns the same (wrong) result: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2H1vWkvDKBPxSY1cqWRrLn/0

Answer (score 0):

Group BY should be use with aggregation function.

(If you need  distinct result use the DISTINCT clause and not use group by improperly)

In mysql versone < 5.7  the The use of group by without aggregation function  produce unpredictable result ..

in mysql >= 5.7 is not allowed by default and this kind of use produce error.

If you want control the result based on group  by you should use a proper aggregation function  eg: min() or max()

```
    SELECT Id 
    FROM Person 
    WHERE Id IN ( SELECT min(Id )
        FROM Person 
        GROUP BY Email
      )
```